# In Delphi 11.3 IDE Editor how do I disable unwanted scrolls on double-click?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm struggling with a very disruptive behavior in Delphi Alexandria 11.3 IDE editor.

When I double-click an identifier, often, but not always, the editor jumps up or down, positioning that identifier at some other vertical position on the page.

I have not detected a pattern regarding which identifiers provoke this behavior, though if an identifier does this, it seems to do it everywhere in the file.

As for the location to which the editor jumps/scrolls, often it seems to scroll the identifier so that it's at the vertical middle of the screen. That leads me to suspect that I have some unwanted fancy scrolling feature enabled.  But the final position is not always in the vertical middle, so maybe not.

Any idea how to get this under control?  Thanks.

Comment: Any IDE plugins installed?

Comment: @JanDoggen No plugins installed.

Comment: Some developer thought they were doing us a favor, and changed the default behavior of the double-click.  It has been SO irritating for months.  Glad to finally have a fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the IDE options and set the highlight word options to none:

Options->User Interface->Editor->Highlight words = None

Comment: I can confirm that, following your suggestion, disabling the "Highlight words" option does indeed cure the scrolling-on-doubleclick problem.  Unfortunately it also defeats one of the purposes of double-clicking a word, which is to see other instances of it. Sigh, one more good feature of the IDE undermined completely or substantially because it's broken in some dumb way.

Comment: You can install the CnPack, it offers this feature and many more.

Comment: It is very irritating when you use a feature for YEARS, and suddenly the DEFAULT behavior changes.  The double-click to highlight all instances of a word (and irritatingly jumping to a different instance than the one I double-clicked) is the most useless feature ever.  I ALWAYS use ctrl+E and then type a word to highlight all of the instances.  It's a bit slower than double-clicking, but at least it works.  THANKS for the tip to fix the double-click.